# Php sqrt function returns wrong number

Tags: php, sqrt

`sqrt(0.0000000185);` returns 0.00013601470. This is ok

`sqrt(0.0000000065);` returns 8.06225774. This is wrong. It had to be 0.000080622577483

How to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: In http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/fc908b23cc477f43286ba0a9cc296e46a9a90794 I get `8.0622577482986E-5` which is correct, if you want to format your number use the [`NumberFormatter`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.numberformatter.php) class

Comment: You're almost certainly getting 8.0622577482986E-5 as the result. Are you performing some other operation on the result before displaying it?

Comment: http://web2.0calc.com/

Comment: To clarify `0.000080622577483` is equal to `8.0622577483 * 10^-5` which is also written as `8.0622577483E-5`

Comment: See this photo: https://scontent.fmad3-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t34.0-12/16933669_641414286046341_1362370968_n.jpg?oh=b73cc4c75cf8e346c0bb639a6bb110b9&oe=58AE923F

Comment: If you would do `8.06225774/100000` (5 Zeros from E-5) the number becomes your `had to be`  `0.000080622577483` Look & See. Ok, only `83` will be missing, because of rounding or else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Mathematical Extensions BC Math

http://php.net/manual/en/function.bcsqrt.php

`echo bcsqrt('0.0000000065',20); //Result 0.00008062257748298549`

Here the number has to be an string!

Note: The basic mathematical functions of php arent that nice...

Have a nice day.